# CSV to JSON: just getting first row not the whole file

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\14103\OneDrive\Desktop\film.csv', encoding='utf-8', 
on_bad_lines='skip')

header= 0

#data.to_json(path_or_buf='my.json',orient='records',lines=True)

data.to_json (r'C:\Users\14103\OneDrive\Desktop\assignments\New_Products.json')
```

I was expecting the whole file to print but only the first row was present

```
{"Year;Length;Title;Subject;Actor;Actress;Director;Popularity;Awards;*Image":
{"0":"INT;INT;STRING;CAT;CAT;CAT;CAT;INT;BOOL;STRING"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the columns in your CSV file are separated by a semicolon instead of a comma. Pandas 'read_csv' function assumes comma-separated values, which is why it reads the entire file as a single row.

To fix it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\14103\OneDrive\Desktop\film.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=';', on_bad_lines='skip')
#data.to_json(path_or_buf='my.json',orient='records',lines=True)
data.to_json(r'C:\Users\14103\OneDrive\Desktop\assignments\New_Products.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```